# I have a Web Application (ASP.NET) made ​​in ArcGIS Server Manager. How to create a button for the user to export his vision for PDF / Image?

Tags: arcgis-server, pdf, asp.net, image

I am using ArcGIS Server Manager to create Web Applications (ASP.NET).

I would like the customer to access has an option to export your vision to PDF or Image, or both.

I would like to generate the file, keep up the zoom, pan, measurements and other iterations that the user made. It would be like a "Print Screen" on your computer, and generates the PDF/Picture file.

I thought about using some javascript API, but not found.

I thought about using Model Builder, but not tried it yet because I think it will not keep the iterations of the user did on the screen: zoom, pan, etc..

I have ArcGIS 10, with SP5.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this export functionality PDF / Image file on a Web Application?

---

**Update:**

I'll try to do this:

[www.codeforge.com/read/132008/ExportMap.cs__html](http://www.codeforge.com/read/132008/ExportMap.cs__html)

In my Web Application standard:

> > \wwwroot\ArcGIS\Manager\Modules\Applications\Templates\mv_cs

Now I'm fixing my computer to to do this. When I do then I'll share with you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the print widget in the ArcGIS Javascript library.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_print.html

*Sorry this wont work if you are not using Server 10.1 or greater*